# Filtering JSON From Twitter's API

Tags: json, node.js, twitter, npm, request

I am currently pulling data from Twitter's API through a Node.js connection running on my computer. Here's the heart of my search:

///

```
var param = {q: "Futbol -filter:retweets -filter:replies", lang: "en", result_type: "popular", count: 10}
client.get('search/tweets',param,function(error,tweets,response){// MY SEARCH GOES HERE}
```

The git repo is here: https://github.com/KingOfCramers/Twitter-Stream-JSON-in-Node

I have a few questions because I am confused about the twitter syntax for Node.js.

First, I pass it to "q" any information relating to a search. What are those parameters called? What page on the Twitter API lists all of them?

Secondly, I am currently passing other arguments as well, such as lang and result_type. I want to tailor my search to specific accounts. Is there a parameter to search by username or the id of the user on Twitter? Eventually I want to stream twitter JSON data from specific groups, like Congresspeople (a different request, client.stream()).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using standard search operators, which are explained [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators). If you want to filter your search by specific accounts, you need to use `from:` query parameter described in that page.

Comment: That works, but it only goes back about a week. Is there a way to get historical tweet data, like searching the entire history of a twitter account? I'm trying to do research into the way tweets are composed, so I need a longer view of the data. Is this possible to do without paying?

Comment: No, the standard api only goes back 1 week. You need an enterprise account for searching in the entire history.